# the boo boys come for me

Tags: phrase-meaning

I guess "the boo boys come for me" mean "the boys who show strong disapproval for me follow me (hunt me as if I am an evil witch)."  Am I on the right track?

I checked up in Oxford Dictionaries which offer this definition "boo-boy: A spectator or supporter who habitually jeers or finds fault; especially (in plural) a particular section or group among the supporters of a team, distinguished as behaving in this manner." This definition doesn't amount to "witch-hunt".

> Sam Harris liked
> Bob Servant tweeted hours ago:

> Sick of the witch-hunt. I am following the rules to the letter. I exercise once a day, locally, with my pets, and still **the boo boys come for me**. I simply can’t win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"witch hunt" is an idiomatic phrase that indicates persecution of any kind.

> 2: the searching out and deliberate harassment of those (such as
> political opponents) with unpopular views
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/witch%20hunt

The implication is that there are many opponents who dislike the person and the boo-boys are an active manifestation of this dislike.

P.S. I don't know who Bob Servant is.